# Let $P \subseteq R^n$ be a polyhedron. Why does $\{ x + \alpha d \mid \alpha > 0\} \subseteq P$ for some $x \in P$ imply $d$ is a recession direction?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Suppose we have a polyhedron $P \subseteq R^n$ and let $d \in P$ be a recession direction, that is $\{ x + \alpha d \mid \alpha > 0\} \subseteq P$ for all $x \in P$.

Why does $\{ x + \alpha d \mid \alpha > 0\} \subseteq P$ for some $x \in P$ imply $d$ is a recession direction ?

Comment: This is only the case if $P$ is a *convex* polyhedron. That is, if $P$ is a *convex* polyhedron and $\{x+\alpha d~|~\alpha>0\}\subseteq P$ for a single $x\in P$, then $\{x+\alpha d~|~\alpha>0\}\subseteq P$ for *all* $x\in P$.

Comment: Special case of [Directions of sublevel sets of a convex function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916163/directions-of-sublevel-sets-ofa-convex-function/916461#916461), the convex function being $1-\chi_P$.

Comment: Isn't any polyhedron convex ?

Comment: In some contexts, convexity may be assumed; but in general, no.  (In fact, some people limit the term "polyhedron" to three dimensions, and reserve "polytope" for the $n$-dimensional case.) If your polyhedron is defined by a system of linear equations and inequalities, then yes it is convex.